# Django model, saving objects

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm developing a small exchange system and I want to give everyone who joins this app a random amount (1-10) of btc. When someone compiles the register form succesfully, recives a random amount of Btc in the wallet. That is my code but doesn't work

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    _id = ObjectIdField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    wallet = models.FloatField()

class Order(models.Model):
    _id = ObjectIdField()
    profile = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    price = models.FloatField()
    quantity = models.FloatField()
```

views.py

```
def registerPage(request):
    bonus = randint(1,10)
    form = CreateUserForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.wallet = bonus
            form.save()

            return redirect('login')

    contex = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'app/register.html', contex)
```

forms.py

```
class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
```

I don't know if is't important but I'm working with Mongodb. Thanks

Comment: Can you add more detail? Is there an error? Also your form doesn't have wallet attribute. Maybe that's a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
def registerPage(request):
    form = CreateUserForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save()
            bonus = random.randint(1,10)
            new_profile = Profile.objects.create(user=new_user, wallet=bonus)
            new_profile.save() # unnecessary after calling `create` but I still do this just in case :)
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = CreateUserForm()
    contex = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'app/register.html', contex)
```

Comment: Doesn't work. no errors but there isn't the new profile in Profile models

Comment: ok, I see where the issue could be, let me update

Comment: suuuuper, Thank you